# where are methods in proxy class "reference.cs"?

Tags: c#, web-services

i'm trying to return a custome object from a web service

object returned only by public fields (variables only not methods)

there are no methods appear in the proxy class

how to call these methods ??

plz help !

Comment: What kind of web service are you talking about? ASP.NET (ASMX) web service? WCF? How did you create it - "Add Reference" or "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio, or some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a custom object with it's method from a web service. You can only return the data in an object.

A web service can be called from any kind of environment, and the methods would only make any sense if the calling environment is pretty much the same as the server environment. You can for example call a web service from a Javascript in a browser, and that environment is not capable of running any .NET methods.

Comment: thnx very much , 
i was wrong 

thnx for this useful information

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you expect that a returned object would contain the methods that it originally has on the webservice server. This is not the case as you experienced. In fact if you think about that webservices are cross-plattform it is somehow obvious that this would be impossible.

If you need methods on a returned object you have to specifiy additional webservices for that.

Comment: thnx very much , 
i was wrong 

thnx for this useful information